# MYSQL procedure to select data with input from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

Using MYSQL, if i have a table SONG with the columns (idSONG, TITLE, LENGTH), a table ARTIST with the columns (idARTIST, SINGLES, BIOGRAPHY), with idARTIST being a fk for ID in a table PEOPLE with columns (ID, NAME), a relation RELEASES (idSONG, idARTIST). How can i make a procedure so that i input an Artists name and it selects all the Songs by that Artist? I know the tables arent really the most efficient but its for a school project.

Comment: Please provide sample data and your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need anything from the `ARTIST` table, so I think that given an artists's name we can join `PEOPLE`, `RELEASES`, and `SONG` to achieve the desired result as follows:

```
SELECT TITLE
FROM SONG S
JOIN RELEASES R ON S.idSONG = R.idSONG
JOIN PEOPLE P ON R.idARTIST = P.ID
WHERE P.NAME = 'insert artist name here';
```